# not getting user email after django facebook login?

Tags: django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I'm trying to login via fb in django. Everything is working fine. Problem is I'm not getting the email of user. I have added `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = [’email’]` to settings.py but I am not getting the email which is important for my database. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and used [this](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/facebook.html#oauth2) in settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
   'fields': 'id, name, email, age_range'
}
SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = True
```

Comment: saved me ton of time )